# saving properties between views in navigation controller?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview, nstimer

i have a navigation controller with a root view controller that is a table view controller. when you click on an individual cell, there is a timer (with label counting down) and start, pause, and continue button. when the view is loaded, the pause and continue button are hidden. when you click the start button, it should disappear and show the pause and continue button, and also the timer will start counting down. for some reason, when i click back on the navigation controller, and re-tap the same cell, none of the properties are loaded (label does not have a countdown time, and the start button is still there even though it should be hidden, and the pause/continue buttons are not there, even though they SHOULD be there). How would I make it so tapping a cell, going back, and re-tapping it show the same properties?
(i dont think delegation is correct because its not a modal VC)

Here is my code:

propertiesviewcontroller.m (what shows up after you click on a cell)

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [_timeLeft setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"BebasNeue" size:25]];
    //if (!([components hour] && [components minute] && [components second]))
    if (startButton.hidden == NO){
        [pauseButton setHidden:YES];
    [continueButton setHidden:YES];
    } else {
        [pauseButton setHidden:NO];
        [continueButton setHidden:NO];
    }
}
-(IBAction)startTimer:(id)sender{
    [sender setHidden:YES];
    [pauseButton setHidden:NO];
    [continueButton setHidden:NO];
        gregorianCalendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
        self.date1 = [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:[testTask timeInterval] sinceDate:[NSDate date]];

        timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(timerAction:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    [timer fire];

}
-(void)timerAction:(NSTimer *)t{
     NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
    components = [gregorianCalendar components:NSHourCalendarUnit|NSMinuteCalendarUnit|NSSecondCalendarUnit  fromDate:now toDate:self.date1 options:0];

    NSString *timeRemaining = nil;
    if([now compare:self.date1] == NSOrderedAscending){
        timeRemaining = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d:%02d", [components hour], [components minute], [components second]];
        NSLog(@"works %@", timeRemaining);
    } else {
        timeRemaining = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"00:00:00"];
        [self.timer invalidate];
        self.timer = nil;
        if (self.alertView == NULL){
       self.alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:[testTask taskName] message:@"Time is up!" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alertView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(show) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];       
        NSLog(@"ended");
        }
    }
   timerLabel.text = timeRemaining;
    [timerLabel setNeedsDisplay];
    [self.view setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

--EDIT-- ViewWillAppear update

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];


    if (startButton.hidden == NO){
        [pauseButton setHidden:YES];
        [continueButton setHidden:YES];
    } else {
        [pauseButton setHidden:NO];
        [continueButton setHidden:NO];
    }
      timeRemaining = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d:%02d", [components hour], [components minute], [components second]];
    timerLabel.text = timeRemaining;
    [timerLabel setNeedsDisplay];
    [self.view setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

--Edit 2-- TableViewController.m

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
 cellSubclassCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"];
    if (!cell)
        cell = [[cellSubclassCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"];

    if([indexPath section] == 0){
    cell.textLabel.text = [[[self.taskArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] taskName] uppercaseString];

    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"unchecked.png"];
        cell.imageView.highlightedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"uncheckedhighlighted.png"];
        [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator];
        [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:236.0/255 green:240.0/255 blue:241.0/255 alpha:1.0f]];
        cell.textLabel.textColor = baseColor;

        NSString *detailText = [[self.taskArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] timeIntervalString];
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = detailText;
               [[cell detailTextLabel] setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Avenir-Black" size:12]];
        [[cell textLabel] setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"AvenirNext-DemiBold" size:16]];
[cell.contentView setAlpha:1];
    } else if ([indexPath section] == 1) {
    cell.textLabel.text = [[[self.completedArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] taskName] uppercaseString];

     cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"checked.png"];
        [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator];
        [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:236.0/255 green:240.0/255 blue:241.0/255 alpha:1.0f]];
        cell.textLabel.textColor = baseColor;
        NSString *detailText = [[self.completedArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] timeIntervalString];
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = detailText;
        [[cell detailTextLabel] setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Avenir-Black" size:12]];
        [[cell textLabel] setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"AvenirNext-DemiBold" size:16]];
        [cell.contentView setAlpha:0.5];
    }
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlechecking:)];
    //cell.contentView
    [cell.imageView addGestureRecognizer:tap];
    cell.imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    return cell;
    }
-(void)handlechecking:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)t{

        CGPoint tapLocation = [t locationInView:self.tableView];
        NSIndexPath *tappedIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:tapLocation];
        NSIndexPath *newIndexPath = nil;

        if (tappedIndexPath.section == 0) {

            NSUInteger newRowIndex = self.completedArray.count;
            [self.completedArray addObject:[self.taskArray objectAtIndex:tappedIndexPath.row]];
            [self.taskArray removeObject:[self.taskArray objectAtIndex:tappedIndexPath.row]];
            newIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:newRowIndex inSection:1];

        } else {

            NSUInteger newRowIndex = self.taskArray.count;
            [self.taskArray addObject:[self.completedArray objectAtIndex:tappedIndexPath.row]];
            [self.completedArray removeObject:[self.completedArray objectAtIndex:tappedIndexPath.row]];
            newIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:newRowIndex inSection:0];
        }
        [self.tableView beginUpdates];
        [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
        [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[tappedIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
        [self.tableView endUpdates];

}
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    NSInteger num = 0;
    if (section == 0) {
        num = self.taskArray.count;
    } else {
        num = self.completedArray.count;
    }
    return num;
}
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    Tasks *task = [[Tasks alloc]init];
    if (indexPath.section == 0){
    task.taskName = [[self.taskArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] taskName];
        task.timeInterval = [[self.taskArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] timeInterval];
    task.dateCreated = [[self.taskArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] dateCreated];
    } else if (indexPath.section == 1){
        task.taskName = [[self.completedArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] taskName];
        task.timeInterval = [[self.completedArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] timeInterval];
        task.dateCreated = [[self.completedArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] dateCreated];
    }
    DetailViewController *dvc = [[DetailViewController alloc]init];
    [dvc setTestTask:task];
    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:dvc animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's why `viewDidLoad` gets called only the first time the view is loaded; to get you problem solved you have to defer those actions you're performing into that method to the `viewWillAppear` method.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated]
    if (startButton.hidden == NO){
        [pauseButton setHidden:YES];
        [continueButton setHidden:YES];
    } else {
        [pauseButton setHidden:NO];
        [continueButton setHidden:NO];
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Ok, your problem is due to the fact your `DetailViewController`s get deallocated each time they are pushed onto the top of the navigation stack, that's why you see the view they controls in the same state you get when you pushed it the first time.

```
// here the detail view controller gets allocated 
DetailViewController *dvc = [[DetailViewController alloc]init];
```

I didn't understand the expected behavior of your task tracking system: in particular the way is determined when a given task can be considered as finished - i.e., the way your countdown logic works for each task( What's supposed to happen for example when you started a task and suddenly your app goes to background, the timer gets stopped then resumed as the app goes back to foreground?, etc. )

Suppose you want that your timer resumes its state as you push back the same view you pushed few instants before,

I suggest you to use a delegate (or block if you will), e.g.

```
- (void)timeElapsed:(NSTimeInterval)secondsElapsed forTask:(NSUInteger)task
{
    //here you can save, e.g., in your task array the remaining seconds the task have to run
    // for example, supposing you're using a linear index to track down the position of the associated timer
    NSTimeInterval remainingSeconds = [self.taskArray[task] timeInterval] - secondsElapsed;
    [self.taskArray[task] setTimeInterval:remainingSeconds];
}
```

The table view controller should implements that method, and the DetailViewController should be initialized with an index relevant to the task associated to.

You also should make the following changes to the DetailViewController in order to message the tableViewController the number of seconds consumed by a given task.

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    [self.timer invalidate];
    self.timer = nil;
    // remember to check if the delegate actually performs that selector
    [delegate timeElapsed:secondsElapsed forTask:taskIndex];
}
```

Comment: that didnt work...when i went back and re tapped the cell the start button was there and the other button werent. also the label was empty (00:00:00)..original post updated with updated code

Comment: what does your code do in the tableview delegate methods? Please post it

Comment: Well my timer is supposed to be like the apple timer...its supposed to continue in the background and send an alert or a UILocalNotification when a task is due. So I don't want to invalidate the timer everytime the view dissapears..

Comment: im trying to make it so you press a start button to start the timer initially, and then press a pause/continue button to stop/start the timer. that way the timer goes on until the time runs out unless the user pauses it

Comment: Ok, in this case it's convenient to decouple the timer logic from your `DetailViewController`, moving that piece of logic into the tableView controller which should be, if I understood correctly, the root view controller. So, even if the user decides to goes back to the table view controller, you can have the timer still running unless he pressed the pause/stop button. In that case you could call back through the delegate the root controller in a way similar to what I've shown you and store in some data structure the remaining time for that given task.

Comment: well the root view controller is a navigation controller, but that root view controller is the tableview controller. will it still work? hhaha